# Mongoose query in MEAN stack

Tags: angularjs, node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mean-stack

I've installed the MEAN stack using the yeoman generator and I would like to implement a query that returns true if a document with a given value for a specific property exists.

It this is the model:

```
    var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
        Schema = mongoose.Schema;

    var FirstSchema = new Schema({
            field1: {
                type: Number,
                trim: true,
                default: ''
        },
        user: {
            type: Schema.ObjectId,
            ref: 'User'
        },
        });

    var SecondSchema = new Schema({
            field1: {
                type: Number,
                trim: true,
                default: ''
            },
            field2: {
                type: String,
            },
            user: {
                type: Schema.ObjectId,
                ref: 'User'
             },
        });

    mongoose.model('First', FirstSchema);
    mongoose.model('Second', SecondSchema);
```

During the creation of Second objects, I assign the $scope.field2 = $stateParams.firstId;

The given query generated by yeoman in the client side is:

```
$scope.find = function() {
            $scope.firsts = Firsts.query();
        };
```

How query if First._id == Second.field2?

Comment: Given how mongoDB (and therefore mongoose) generate IDs there is a near impossibility that two documents (even in different collections) would have the same ID unless you have explicitly set them to the same value.

Comment: Hi Jason, thank you for your answer. 
You're right, I've formulated the question in a wrong way. I've just corrected the question with the right information.